# What is an easy way to get money in Splatoon 2?

Tags: splatoon-2, splatoon-2-octo-expansion

I feel it takes me too long to grind up money in splatoon 2. I'm currently trying to get all weapons and gear. (Mainly weapons)  I often use tickets and go to grizzco but is there something better? And yes I do have the octo expansion and try for money there.

Answer (score 3):

Update:

The only way to really get money flowing in quickly, **is to play ranked in S+.**

Once you are in S+ rankings, you get a tremendous amount of money every game.

Indeed, you will rapidly max out your money at 9999999. And then it doesn't matter.

Now that I'm maxed out at 9999999, I just spend money pointlessly for the hell of it - and straight-away you get maxed out at 9999999 again.

So unfortunately it's a catch-22

1. Effectively, you don't get lots of money flowing in fast until you very likely are already maxed out at 9999999
2. Once you are in S+ ranks, you get plenty of money flowing in, but you really don't need it
3. Early in the game before S rank, you really need the money (so as to scrub for gear, buy weapons, etc), but (see below) the plain fact is *there is no way* to get money fast in Splatoon2 (until you're in S+, and you don't need it).

---

I've come to believe there's just **no easy way** to get money in Splatoon2.

- If you play Turf, you'll win about 50% of games, because of the way the teams are chosen. (If you're awesome, you'll be placed with poor players. If you're new, you'll be placed with top players.  So the fact is .......... you only win about 50% on Turf Wars. No matter what sort of player you are.)
- If you play Ranked - you get a lot when you win. However: When you LOSE in Ranked you get nothing. Unfortunately, over time, it's not clear you actually get more playing Ranked than Turf. :/
- It's 5 mins for Ranked and only 3 mins for Turf. A huge difference when you're farming.
- There are many more DCs in Turf than Ranked. A huge time waste when farming.
- Regarding the whole food/drinks **tickets system**. It takes so long to get tickets. They only last a **tiny 20 games**. Unfortunately, I fear **it's not worth it**.  In the huge amount of time it takes to gain tickets, you could have simply played a pile of Ranked or Turf and taken home all that cash.
- Say you are farming for chunks. Say you're in the A games on Ranked.  *You won't win unless you have your best gear sets on!!* So in the higher levels, when you have chunk-farming gear on, you won't win anyway.  :/

*Minor tip on tickets:*

You actually get **a few free tickets** by simply looking at the "Switch News" help items. ([Search](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2019/02/splatoon_2_news_channel_giving_out_free_drink_tickets_next_week).)  At least, that gives you a few games where you get 1.5x cash.

*Save some cash with Splatfest snails*

Farming for gear, you can do one of two things. (A) pay 20,000 per scrub. (B) Re-roll, for 1x super sea snail. 30x snail-rerolls saves 600,000 cash.  So that's one way to save some cash, at least. Each Splatfest gives you 20+ super sea snails.

---

Answer (score 2):

I suggest playing Ranked, as you seem to be quite a dedicated player and the higher your rank, the more cash you'll earn.

Comment: I'm about S rank and I earn way more than in Turf War, even considering the time.

Answer (score -1):

So here is how to get money fairly quickly. Go to Turf War, equip good gear, (examples of good abilities: swim speed up, run speed up, ink saver main, ink saver sub, special power up and ink recovery up.) and maybe use some tickets, too. If you are a fairly low level, you will get put with high leveled people, and vice versa.
You get a decent amount of money if you win and you get a little bit if you lose. (in Ranked you don't get money if you lose)